# How to compare two SVN revisions using TortoiseSVN command line?

Tags: command-line, compare, tortoisesvn, revision

Let's say we have two revisions needed to be compare i.e. `r1` and `r2`.

Normally we 1) open SVN log using TortoiseSVN, then 2) pick up the two revision from the log, and 3) compare them - details as snapshots below.

My question is how can we do the same thing via TortoiseSVN command-line, i.e. [TortoiseProc.exe](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)?

p.s.

Looking at [official guide](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) from TortoiseSVN page, link me to `/command:showcommand` but I failed to build a successful complete command call with its arguments such as `url1`, `url2`, `revision1`, and `revision2`

I'm using local SVN repository created at folder `F:\Desktop\aa` on my PC; checked-out at `F:\Desktop\aaco`

My command that failed is as below

`tortoiseproc /command:showcompare /url1:file:///F:/Desktop/aaco /revision1:1 /url2:file:///F:/Desktop/aaco /revision2:3`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by you failed to build a successful complete command? `tortoiseproc /command:showcompare 
/url1:https://mysvn/svn/Test/bar/foo.txt /revision1:1 
/url2:https://mysvn/svn/Test/bar/foo.txt /revision2:2` is this what you are running??

Comment: My SVN repo is a local repo created on my hard drive i.e. I call `tortoiseproc /command:showcompare /url1:` **file:///d:/path/to/foo.txt**  `/revision1:1 /url2:` **file:///d:/path/to/foo.txt** `/revision2:2`

Comment: So, I failed to put in the `url` for local SVN repo I guess

Comment: Settings dialog->Advanced. Set "Debug" to "true". Then do the diff. With debug set to true, every TSVN command will first pop up a dialog showing you the exact parameters for the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct command should be as below - the url must point to the local repo folder instead of the checkout one.

tortoiseproc /command:showcompare **/url1:file:///F:/Desktop/aa** /revision1:1 **/url2:file:///F:/Desktop/aa** /revision2:3